# Xamarin OpenCV ICvCameraViewListener

Tags: android, opencv, xamarin

For a while I'm having issue trying to implement **ICvCameraViewListener**. I inherit it , implement its methods, yet they're not called at all. Tried on both **Activity** and **JavaCameraView**.

Looking at the OpenCV for Android java sample code, there is a line:
**mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);**
but there is no such a method in **JavaCameraView** nor in **CameraBridgeViewBase**.

I can go via **OnPreviewFrame()** callback method, but then what is the point of **ICvCameraViewListener** interface if I have to convert byte[] to Mat myself.

Also this alternative approach gives some unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

After sharing experiences with [AlessandroRizzotto](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/comments/59195/AlessandroRizzotto) on official Xamarin forum, we came up with the solution for this problem.

So the problem was in resolving API differences between source OpenCV and converted code. As **setCvCameraViewListener** was set to private/protected in OpenCV it was not translated to c#. In order to overcome this issue, some extra effort is required in Binding project ( the one containing OpenCV source ).

In Transforms/Metadata.xml next code snippet should be added:

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='org.opencv.android']/class[@name='CameraBridgeViewBase']">
  <method name="setCvCameraViewListener" return="void" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public" >
    <parameter name="listener" type="org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener"/>
  </method>
</add-node>
```

After that, you'll be able to access missing method, and everything else works just like a charm.

Whole discussion can be found on this [address](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/122475/)